# browser showing model as query string in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

having an issue in asp.net  mvc, browser is displaying complete model as part of query string.

I have first method which gives list of employees

```
   [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetEmployees()
    {
          model.employees = GetEmployeeList()
      return View(model);
    }

   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult DisplayEmployee(Guid id)
   {
    model.emp=GetEmployeeDetails(id);
     return View("GetEmployees",model);
   }
```

I am getting the complete query string as following

```
StakeWorking=ColloSys.DataLayer.Domain.StkhWorking&StkHolder=ColloSys.DataLayer.Domain.Stakeholders&StkhPaymentP=ColloSys.DataLayer.Domain.StkhPayment&StakeAddress=ColloSys.DataLayer.Domain.GAddress&StakeAddressDetails=ColloSys.UserInterface.Models.StakeAddressDetails&StkhWorkingDetails=ColloSys.UserInterface.Models.StakeWorkingDetails&ListOfRegion=System.Collections.Generic.List%601%5BSystem.String%5D&ListOfProduct=System.Collections.Generic.List%601%5BSystem.String%5D
```

Comment: What does your view looks like? Without the code for the View it is impossible to say why it outputs the given string.

Comment: Can  you shared the code of your View?

Comment: Can you share the code for your **Form tag** in view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved. Actually problem in the post method of DisplayEmployee action
i tried this and problem is solved

```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult DisplayEmployee(Guid id)
   {
    model.emp=GetEmployeeDetails(id);
     return View("GetEmployees");
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check your view for model binding is done correctly.

Take look [here.. a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510856/c-sharp-mvc-return-viewobject-results-in-a-querystring)